# Mongodb:ACCESS [main] error opening file: /mongo/key.txt: bad file

Tags: mongodb

1. Generated the key.txt

> openssl rand -base64 666 > /mongo/key.txt
>   chmod 600 /mongo/key.txt

2. Command

> --keyFile=/mongo/key.txt --replSet=MONGO_EDU_SET --dbpath=/mongo/data --logpath=/mongo/logs/a.log --logappend

```
2019-09-05T07:01:23.625+0000 I  ACCESS   [main] error opening file: /mongo/key.txt: bad file
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

In my case a key file was mounted to `/opt/keyfile` with permission `0600,root,root` (on host), inside docker image it was `0600,1000,1000`.

To solve the problem, I changed the permissions in host to `999,999` (translated to `systemd-coredump`), but inside docker user 999 was translated to `mongodb`.

So, to fix it, you just need to call (on host):

```bash
chown 999:999 key-path-on-host
```

Comment: Just to note that you are doing `chown 999:999` not `chmod 999`

Comment: `chown 999:999` worked for me on mongodb 4.4, also mounting the file in a docker container with `:ro` option (might not be necessary though).

Answer (score 8):

Check the owner and attributes of /mongo/key.txt in container. It must be like this:

```
root@243810c57e61:/# ll /etc/mongo/replkey 
-r-------- 1 mongodb root 1024 Sep 27 12:19 /etc/mongo/replkey
```

Answer (score 5):

The response for `ls -la` in the host should be like

```
-r-------- 1 systemd-coredump root 1024 jul  8 11:12 keyfile/mongo-cluster-key
```

I fixed the problem entering to the container and doing a `chown mongodb keyfile/mongo-cluster-key`

Also, i think you could do it throught the host with:

```
$ chown systemd-coredump keyfile/mongo-cluster-key
```

Comment: Just to note, `chown 999 `does the same thing, probably cleaner. 999 is the user id that mongo runs under in docker.

Answer (score 1):

The key file should be owned by `mongod:mongod` user on linux and have `400` read permissions

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set this up for development, the key file is no longer necessary in Mongo 5. See here for an example: https://github.com/UpSync-Dev/docker-compose-mongo-replica-set

Note this turns off authentication so don't derp your derpy-derp.

up.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

docker compose up --remove-orphans
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:5
    container_name: mongo1
    command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30001"]
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data1:/data/db
      # only run this on one server
      #- ./initDb.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initDb.js:ro
    ports:
      - 30001:30001
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'my-replica-set',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongo1:30001\"},{_id:1,host:\"mongo2:30002\"},{_id:2,host:\"mongo3:30003\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --port 30001 --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:5
    container_name: mongo2
    command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30002"]
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data2:/data/db

    ports:
      - 30002:30002

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:5
    container_name: mongo3
    command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30003"]
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data3:/data/db
    ports:
      - 30003:30003

  mongo_express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongo1:30001,mongo2:30002,mongo3:30003/?replicaSet=my-replica-set
      - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=pastel-on-dark
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
      - mongo3

volumes:
  mongodb_data1:
  mongodb_data2:
  mongodb_data3:
```

Note the connection string doesn't have auth in it:

```
mongodb://mongo1:30001,mongo2:30002,mongo3:30003/?replicaSet=my-replica-set
```